# Click on Same coordinates repeatedly using Selenium Python inside a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to click on particular coordinates (200,200) using selenium inside a python for the loop.

I am using "`ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(axis_x, axis_y).click().perform()`" to perform click operation using python selenium.
In the first iteration, it works fine but in the second iteration, I am facing a problem. Actually, in the first iteration selenium takes the coordinates as (200,200), but in the second iteration, it takes the coordinates value as (400,400) and performs a click. i.e initially cursor is at [200,200] coordinates and it add [200,200] to initial value.
Is there is any way so that I can initialize the coordinates to (0,0) each time?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/')
for i in range(5):         
     driver.findelementby_xpath("//input[@name='q']").send_keys("hey")
     actions = ActionChains(driver)
     X = 550
     Y = 331
     actions.move_by_offset(X,Y).click().perform()
```

Comment: Are you able to share the code snippet? Cannot really comment otherwise

Comment: @Ali Has added the code snippet above. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
X = 550
Y = 331
```

and in a loop so after 1st iteration based on your screen size if co-ordinates are not found, you will get `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds`

This should work for you :

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
X = 10
Y = 10
counter = 0
for i in range(5):
     ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")
     ele.send_keys("hey" + Keys.RETURN)
     ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(X,Y).click().perform()
     X = X + 10
     Y = Y + 10
     print("Iteration number ", counter)
     counter = counter + 1
```

or in case you do not want to increment co-ordinates :

```
X = 10
Y = 10
counter = 0
for i in range(5):
     ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")
     ele.send_keys("hey" + Keys.RETURN)
     ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(X,Y).click().perform()
     X = 0
     Y = 0
     print("Iteration number ", counter)
     counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet below resetting the value of X and Y to 0.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/')
for i in range(5):         
     driver.findelementby_xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']").click()
     actions = ActionChains(driver)
     X = 200
     Y = 200
     actions.move_by_offset(X,Y).click().perform()
     X, Y = 0, 0
```

Comment: No , the above code is giving me error. Initilization of coordinates is not working.
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds